# Can we tell who originally close-voted a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If someone has had a mis-spent past few years accruing rep on EL&U, and one therefore has enough reputation, one can view the review queue and see who has been voting to close or keep open a particular question.

What I'd like to know is how and whether members can see who originally voted to close a question, and who else  voted to close it *before* it hits the close-vote queue.

Is there a way to  access this information?

Comment: No. Once the question is closed, you can see the names, and if it’s subsequently re-opened (and re-closed, deleted, undeleted, re-opened, ad nauseum), the names of the voters for *successful* actions are recorded in the post history. But until an action is successful, usernames of individual voters are not available. What would you do with this information / why do you want it?

Answer (score 3):

## For 10k Users Only

With one notable exception, no, immoderatorial users cannot *normally* know such things.

However, 10k users are granted added oversight capabilities to help police the site under the principles of scalable community moderation. They are therefore potentially able to see at least some of those pending close-votes by examining recent relevant entries from the [close vote review queue history](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).

Mind you, those will only be the close-votes that happened via that review queue. But it's more than nothing.

### *Please use this power for good, not for evil*

Just like with anything else on the site that catches your eye as being possibly dodgy, if you think you see anything untoward happening there in the history listing, please custom-flag any (preferably related) post for moderator attention and include your concern in the detailed text you send us with the flag.

Because moderators have much greater visibility into site operations than even 10k users have, we can take the ball and quietly investigate your concern more deeply — and, should the situation warrant it, take appropriate action.

Comment: *Immoderatorial*?  Is this (unpronounceable) sophisticated-speak for *non-moderator*?

Comment: @aparente001 I think it’s a fantastic word.

Comment: @DanBron - That suggests that you've figured out how to pronounce it.  Please, record it and post a link!

Comment: @aparente001 It would be *immodest* of me to deny tchrist the privilege of doing that himself.

Comment: @aparente001 Whatcha talkin’ ’bout Willis? It is of course pronounced just exactly as you see it spelled: [ɨ̃ˌmɒɾəɻəˈtʰoɻʷiʲəɫ]. Everybody knows that! :)

Comment: A simpler term for "immoderatorial users" would be _immoderati_.

Comment: The  [OED](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=immoderatorial&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch) has no listing for immoderatorial, but it does for moderatorial.  [OED, moderatorial](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120613?redirectedFrom=moderatorial#eidl) :"Of, relating to, or characteristic of a moderator or chairman".  "Chiefly Christian church."  Thus, immoderatorial must mean "un-tchrist-like", not "without the powers of tchrist."  Whatever, the word deserves a hat.

Comment: @aparente001 See [this intro to IPA vowels](http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/67308552090/how-to-remember-the-ipa-vowel-chart) and [this intro to IPA consonants](http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/143133795554/how-to-remember-the-ipa-consonant-chart).